# How do you specify a version using brew cask?

Tags: homebrew

How do I specify a version number when installing something with `brew cask install`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For recent versions of Homebrew, [Jethro' instructions below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58373705/8280495) may not work work, because we will get an error like:

> Invalid usage: Non-checksummed download of <FORMULA_NAME> formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported.

I found a workaround:

1. Go to the Homebrew Cask search page: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/
2. Type and find the application you are looking for
3. Click `Cask code` link
4. On Github click `History` button
5. Find the version you need by reading the commit messages and view the raw file. Confirm the version variable (normally on line 2) is the version you need.
6. Click on the `name of the commit`, then `three dots` and select `View file`
7. Right-click `Raw` button and `Save Link As...` to download the file locally
8. When downloaded, go to download directory `cd Downloads/`
9. Finally run `brew install --cask <FORMULA_NAME>.rb`
10. Voilà

If you need some visual assistance check the screenshots [here](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/03/install-brew-package-version/).

Comment: I was going to suggest using the file's URL instead of downloading it.  Then I realized it was basically the same thing as @jethro's solution, which is apparently problematic for some people.  It worked for me, though.  I was able to install dbeaver-community v. 22.3.5, using the command: `brew install --cask https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/26c51fdcd344f1b08b56aed88dafdac660236df8/Casks/dbeaver-community.rb`.  Note that getting specific versions of casks works with Homebrew's `upgrade` command as well as `install`.

Comment: yep using the github url works perfectly - easier than downloading yourself

Comment: For step 7 above: GitHub now has a "Download raw file" button (the downward arrow icon), so you can use this instead

Answer (score 15):

The other answers are pretty heavy handed, an alternative is to use the **homebrew/cask-versions** tap which contains a list of the old (major) versions of casks.

To use them tap it with:

```bash
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
```

To see if what you're looking for is there, search for your cask again with:

```bash
brew search --cask yourformula
```

Or you can see the complete list of casks by clicking on **Casks** folder at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions .

Answer (score 12):

You can manually point brew at the ruby file for a specific version of a cask, using a git hash.  This lets you control which version is installed.

For example:

1. Find the [cask .rb file](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/commits/master/Casks/minikube.rb) on the homebrew-cask git repo that you
   want.
2. Get the commit hash, eg
   `cee7983cd95fc92fdc250fc509f2379cefe647fe` in the example above.

   Git may give you instructions to view the file history locally - eg `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask.git` `git log master -- Casks/CASK_NAME.rb`
3. Point brew at the file using the hash: `brew cask install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/cee7983cd95fc92fdc250fc509f2379cefe647fe/Casks/minikube.rb`

Comment: Trying the above, I get "Error: Calling Non-checksummed download of curl formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled!". The suggestion to use `wget` followed by `brew install --HEAD -s your-file.rb` from  here worked for me: https://dev.to/gjrdiesel/getting-around-brew-s-error-calling-non-checksummed-download-of-17fl

Answer (score 5):

If you run

```
brew edit [formula]
```

you can change the version that matches your operating system. If you know the checksum, enter that too. If not, just comment that line out with `#` and it will skip the check. Then run

```
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew reinstall [formula]
```